# Prove the growth of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Consider a function defined by 
$f(1) =1$
$f(2)=2$
$f(n)=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$ for all $n>2$. Show that this function grows exponentially.

how can I prove this using Master theorem, not using any other method, only master theorem

Comment: What is "Master's theorem"? Do you have to say "Sir" when you use it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple linear recurrence relation like $f(n)=af(n-1)+bf(n-2)$, where $a,b$ are constants, it is not hard to show that $f(n)=Ah^n+Bk^n$, where $A,B$ are constants and $h,k$ satisfy the quadratic equation $x^2=ax+b$.

So in this case you have $f(n)=Ah^n+Bk^n$, where $h=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2},k=\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$. Note that $h>1$ and $|k|<1$. You can easily get $A,B$ from $f(1)=1,f(2)=2$. You will find that $f(n)$ is the nearest integer to $Ah^n$, which represents exponential growth.